# Unix Timer to use in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, timer

I want to run a shell scipr that prints out the top 50 lines of a number of files. After the head of each file is printed, I want the script to allow the user to view that content for 10 seconds before printing out the head of the next file. E.g

```
head -n 50 file1
wait 10 seconds
head -n 50 file2
wait 10 seconds
```

and so on...

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
for f in *
do
 head -n 50 $f
 sleep 10;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *sleep* within an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to watch some output with `$n` seconds interval, use

```
watch -n $n <commands here>
```

Comment: The OP wants to pause between viewing different files, not view the same file repeatedly.